# Trigger event or call function on initialization

Tags: r, shiny

I have an action button with an observer, which loads a chart and some text fields based on user-provided input. When a button is clicked, my function is called, which is all well and good. However, what I would like is for the function to run when the page first loads.

I'm not sure if I should be trying to manually trigger the event (or how to go about doing that), or is there a way to call a function on initialization?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("run", "Run"),
  textInput("input_field")
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$text1 <- renderText({
    return('text 1')
  })

  output$text2 <- renderText({
    //use input field to get correct data
    return(getTextOutput(input$input_field))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
     //use input field to get correct data
     plot(getChartData(input$input_field))
  })

  observeEvent(input$run, {
    populateScreen(input, output)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want, can you include a reproducible example?

Comment: What are you confused about? I show a chart when the button is clicked (the chart changes based on values in input fields). I would like to show the chart when the page first loads, based on the default input values.

Comment: Sorry but several functions in your example do not exist (`getTextOutput`, `getChartData`, `populateScreen`, etc.) and I don't know how to replace them. Can you modify it?

Comment: I'm using those function names as examples to show that I'm populating the text fields and chart somehow, the details of which aren't pertinent. The point is that I would like to retrieve data from several different functions at once when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the event to run when it's first created, add `ignoreInit = FALSE, ignoreNULL = FALSE` as parameters to `observeEvent`

```
observeEvent(input$submit_streaks, {
    populateStreaks(input, output)
}, ignoreInit = FALSE, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

From the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html),

> **ignoreNULL = FALSE and ignoreInit = FALSE**
>
> This combination means that handlerExpr will run every time no matter what.